# access to javascript variables in laravel

Tags: javascript, laravel

how can I access javascript variables in blade laravel?

for example

```
  var counter = 1;


 {{ dd(counter) }}
```

it gives me this error

> Use of undefined constant counter - assumed 'counter' (this will throw
> an Error in a future version of PHP)

Comment: PHP runs server-sider, JavaScript runs in the browser. No.

Answer (score 1):

You can't. You need to use JavaScript to inject the values to the Blade templates. Basically you need to do this in a `script` tag.

```php
<p id="counter"></p>

<script>
var counter = 0;

counter++;

document.querySelector('#counter').innerHTML = counter;
</script>
```

Comment: you know I have a dynamic input that when user click on + new input is come . so I want to use this "counter" for old() helper laravel

Comment: In that case, you need to create the inputs dynamically and add them to the container element using the `appendChild` function (https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_node_appendchild.asp).

Comment: I am using append .. but each new inputs are a group that have a old()

Answer (score 0):

Its better to add any id where you want to show veriable then select this element using query selector

```
<div id="show_variable"></div>
```

and use jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 var countor = 0;
 counter++;
 $('#show_variable').html(counter)
});
```

Comment: you know I have a dynamic input that when user click on + new input is come . so I want to use this "counter" for old() helper laravel

Comment: its mean you are using counter as a id to identify input  ?

Comment: something like this